# API response after field subtraction with Prisma Client

Tags: prisma, next.js13

I want to get a new response list, but don't know how to handle this with Prisma Client.

Here is a part of my route.ts file in Next.js 13

```
  const consumption2021 = await prisma.apt_elec_consump.groupBy({
    where: {
      month: {
        gt: 6,
        lt: 12,
      },
      year: {
        equals: 2021,
      },
    },
    by: ["apartment_id", "year"],
    _sum: {
      consumption: true,
    },
  });
  const consumption2022 = await prisma.apt_elec_consump.groupBy({
    where: {
      month: {
        gt: 6,
        lt: 12,
      },
      year: {
        equals: 2022,
      },
    },
    by: ["apartment_id", "year"],
    _sum: {
      consumption: true,
    },
  });
```

What I want to do is get a new list after subtraction between consumption2021 and consumption2022.
After that, I will show only top 10 items in order of results of subtraction

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue and want to share what it is.

```
const subtraction = consumption2022.map((item, index) => {
return {
  apartment_id: item.apartment_id,
  result:
    Number(item._sum.consumption) -
    Number(consumption2021[index]._sum.consumption),
};
```

happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can first calculate the difference between `consumption2022` and `consumption2021` and then sort the resulting list by this difference. Here's how you can do it:

1. Calculate the difference:

   ```
   const consumptionDiff = consumption2022.map((entry2022) => {
   ```

   const entry2021 = consumption2021.find((entry201) =>
   entry201.apartment_id === entry2022.apartment_id
   );

   if (entry2021) {
   return {
   apartment_id: entry2022.apartment_id,
   year: entry2022.year,
   difference: entry2022._sum.consumption - entry2021._sum.consumption,
   };
   }

   return null;
   });

This code calculates the difference for each entry in `consumption2022` by finding the corresponding entry in `consumption2021` based on the `apartment_id`. If a matching entry is found, it calculates the difference and creates a new object with the `apartment_id`, `year`, and `difference` properties. If there is no matching entry in `consumption2021`, it returns `null`.

2. Filter out null entries and sort by the difference:

   const validConsumptionDiff = consumptionDiff.filter((entry) => entry !== null);

   validConsumptionDiff.sort((a, b) => b.difference - a.difference);

This code filters out any null entries from the `consumptionDiff` array and then sorts the array in descending order based on the `difference` property.

3. Get the top 10 items:

   const top10ConsumptionDiff = validConsumptionDiff.slice(0, 10);

This code uses `slice` to get the first 10 items in the sorted `validConsumptionDiff` array, which will give you the top 10 items based on the difference.

Now, `top10ConsumptionDiff` contains the top 10 entries with the greatest differences between `consumption2022` and `consumption2021`, sorted in descending order. You can use this list to display the results as needed in your application.

Comment: Thank you for replying! That is better answer than that of mine in validation